# Integration by substitution of $x\log(x)$

Tags: integration, substitution

I have the integral
$$\int x\log(x)\ dx,$$
and I need to solve it by substitution. 
I don't know why, if you substitute $x$ by $g(y)$ you have $x= e^y$ and the integral of $e^y \cdot y \cdot e^y\ dy$ and the the integral of $e^{x^2}\cdot x\ dx$.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! Integration by parts would be easier. Do you really want a solution by substitution ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Mathematical expressions can be posted on the site using [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: It's not $e^{x^2}$, it's $(e^x)^2 = e^{2x}$.

Answer (score 3):

Try integration by parts, i.e. use:$$\int u\,dv=uv-\int v\,du$$
A prudent set of substitutions here would be:
$$\begin{align}
u&=\log(x)\\
dv&=x \, dx
\end{align}$$
Hopefully you can finish this off

---

As noted by @SimonS below, you asked to do this by substitution alone. In which case try the substitution:$$u=2x^2\log(x)-x^2$$This leads to:$$du=4x\log(x)\,dx$$
Hopefully you can finish this off

Comment: One of the beaties of Liebnitz' notation. $x dx= d(x^2/2).$

Comment: The question asks for substitution

Comment: @SimonS I have added a solution based purely on substitution as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

There was an error in the arithmetic.  Note that

$$e^y\,y\,e^y=ye^{2y}\ne ye^{y^2}$$

Therefore, we can write

$$\int x\log(x)\,dx=\int ye^{2y}\,dy$$

where $x=e^y$ or $y=\log(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $\ln x = z$ leads to $$\int x \ln(x) \, dx=\int z e^{2z} \, dz$$

The second integral can be easily calculated by integration by parts.

Comment: Note proper MathJax usage, as in my edits to this answer. ${}\qquad{}$